# How to extract a single string from a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve a json document from my mongodb, and after fetching it extract only a single field say "email" so that I can use it to send emails to the users

```
setInterval(()=>{        
            return User.find({email: 'qw@qw'})
                .then(doc => {
                    console.log(doc);
                    console.log(doc.name)
                 })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("error")
                })
    }, 5000)
```

**My schema**:

```
const
    mongoose                = require("mongoose"),

// MONGOOSE MODEL CONFIGURATION
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    email:{
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My JSON looks like:

```
[ { _id: 5b892cdc060e8d000405d304,
    email: 'qw@qw',
    name: 'john',
    phone: '111111111'
    __v: 0 } ]
```

`console.log(doc.name)` returned `"undefined"`

Can anybody help me out on how to do this properly?

Comment: What does your JSON look like? What do you get in `doc`?

Comment: JSON is a format. What you're getting is an Object called `doc`, and you are logging it to the console. The result of that will tell you exactly what properties `doc` has.

Comment: @Chris G, i tried `console.log(doc.email)` undefined and `console.log(email)` flags an error

Comment: @FischerBaba Again, JSON is a **FORMAT** of text, very similar to how JavaScript Object literals look like. `doc` is an Object, not JSON. Anyway, you probably need `doc[0].name`, since `doc` is an array.

Comment: JSON v Object: https://jsfiddle.net/28gab79p/

Comment: @ChrisG This `doc[0].name` worked for me, if i was an answer i would have marked it as accepted!!! Thanks !!!

Comment: @FischerBaba — I posted that as an answer a few minutes before Chris G's comment was made.

Comment: @FischerBaba You're welcome, but how to access an object's children is a) an extremely basic thing and b) keeps getting asked again and again and has probably dozens of existing duplicates by now.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVgpwm?editors=1111

Comment: lol somebody removed extra ]  bracket from end  [ { _id: 5b892cdc060e8d000405d304,
    email: 'qw@qw',
    name: 'john',
    phone: '111111111'
    __v: 0 } ] ]

Answer (score 1):

> My JSON looks like
>
> ```
> [ { _id: 5b892cdc060e8d000405d304,
> ```

*(If that really is JSON, then the first thing you need to do is convert it to JavaScript with `JSON.parse`. I doubt the `find` method is presenting you with JSON though.)*

You are trying to read the `name` property of an object, but `doc` is not that object.

Look at the `[`!

It is an array *containing* that object.

You need to extract the object from the array (e.g. with `doc[0]` or a loop) and then read the name property from that.

Possibly you might want to use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Answer (score -1):

Please find updated answer. Since it has extra `]` at end and I pointed out.
Update : `Mongo db` is returning `BSON` convert it to valid JSON format in API layer.

Try to have everything as quoted as mentioned below.
I have updated code pen also.

Corrected according to previous comments and Chris G inputs.

```
var json = '[{ "_id": "5b892cdc060e8d000405d304" ,"email": "qw@qw", "name": "john", "phone": "111111111"      }]';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj[0].email);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj[0].phone);
```

example:

```
var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj.result);
// expected output: true
```

now in  your case its invalid json. I see extra square braces at end most keys are not in quotes.

```
var json = '{ "_id": "5b892cdc060e8d000405d304" ,"email": "qw@qw", "name": "john", "phone": "111111111"      }';
obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.email);
// expected output: 42

console.log(obj.phone);
// expected output: true
```

Check here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVgpwm?editors=1111

Comment: This question isn't about parsing JSON. mongodb doesn't return JSON. And you missed the crux of the question, namely that `doc` is an *array* and thus requires `[0]` first before accessing `.name`

Comment: Mongodb does not return json it returns bson .

Comment: I don't know what your point is. How do you read my first comment, then go on to send me to a codepen that reiterates your irrelevant code example?

Comment: @chris G thanks I updated codepen new code .Asked him to Convert bson to json format .

Comment: I don't know if this is a language barrier problem. In OP's code `doc` is a **JAVASCRIPT OBJECT**. It is *not* JSON, and it is *not* BSON. Nothing has to be parsed. The question *ISN'T* about JSON.